# Android Work Profile Sandbox Policy restrict permissions to access files

Tags: android, profile, policy

I have an Android Application published with Android Work Profile. The problem is that all the documents downloaded by the app go into the Downloads folder of the work profile, where no other app has privileges.

If I want to open the image/pdf or any other file from Downloads, it says „Can't open file”. The problem is that neither my application can't start an activity to open the image or pdf because starting a new activity for view need the system's default applications.

How do I manage to set the policies in order to access the resources from the work profile without having to move them in the personal space?

I couldn’t find the right settings in the Google Admin and I need to solve this in the right way.

So, this is the code to download the pdf

```
 private void downloadPdf(View uiIcon, String branch, ProgressBar progressBar, String diferentiator) {
    uiIcon.setEnabled(false);
    final int orderIDbis = orderID;

    GetDataService downloadService = RetrofitClientInstance.createService(GetDataService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = downloadService.directURLDownload(branch + orderID);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            uiIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +
                        File.separator + "3dentaAdmin");
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.mkdir();
                }
                String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +
                        File.separator + "3dentaAdmin" + "/" + orderIDbis + "_" + diferentiator + ".pdf";
                fileToSave = new File(path);
                try {
                    fileToSave.createNewFile();
                    byte[] bytes = response.body().bytes();
                    Files.asByteSink(fileToSave).write(bytes);

                    openFileWithFileProvider("application/pdf");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                uiIcon.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nu s-a putut descarca", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                uiIcon.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nu s-a putut descarca", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            uiIcon.setEnabled(true);
            uiIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

And this code is used to open the file

```
private void openFileWithFileProvider(String fileType) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {

        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        install.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(ActivityScannerResult.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileToSave), fileType);
        install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(install);

    } else {

        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileToSave.getAbsolutePath())), fileType);
        install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(install);

    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to download the files?

Comment: I've added the code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that all the documents downloaded by the app go into the Downloads folder of the work profile, where no other app has privileges.

If you download to Private External Storage you won't have that problem?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

i.e. use `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the primary shared/external storage device where the application can place persistent files it owns. These files are internal to the applications, and not typically visible to the user as media.

From my understanding of the WorkProfile, apps are sandboxed and should not be allowed to open files from the public downloads folder. If it where possible its a decision of the IT Management of the Work Profile, not a permission in an individual app.

I had a look through https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/work-profile but at a glance can't find a specific quote to clarify that.